# SQL Server truncation error with specific column name

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

When a string of data is too long for a column in a table, I get the following message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.

I've seen that in recent SQL Server editions, the error will include the column that is being truncated.

Is it just the SQL Server edition that causes the column to be included or is there a setting that must be turned on for the SQL Server engine to include which column is the cause of the truncation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Verbose truncation warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#verbose_truncation_warnings---on--off-) is a database-scoped configuration available in SQL Server 2019 and later versions (regardless of edition). When set to ON under database compatibility level 150 (SQL 2019) or higher, you'll get more details of the truncated column and value.

```
USER YourDatasbase;
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION
SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;
```

Comment: Thank you, and that makes sense.  We do have SQL Server 2019.  When I run that and then run my insert with the long data, I do not get the verbose warning.  Do I need to do a reset of the SQL services for the change to take effect?

Update: Compatibility was 140.  Must be 150 or higher.