# How to fix the error String or binary data would be truncated in SQL Server 2019 with linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to pinpoint the column in the table when data insert into a table throws generic error ***String or binary data would be truncated*** in SQL Server 2019. So, whenever data is inserted to any of the ProductName greater than data length 100, ProductDescription greater than data length 500, Comment greater than data length 500 I would want to know which column truncation error is throwing.

***SQL:***

```
CREATE TABLE dest_server.dest_db_name.dbo.Products
         (ID             INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
          ProductID      INT,
          ProductName    VARCHAR(100),
          ProductDescription VARCHAR(500),
          Comment  VARCHAR(500))
          
CREATE TABLE src_db_name.dbo.SourceProducts
         (ID             INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
          ProductID      INT,
          ProductName    VARCHAR(250),
          ProductDescription VARCHAR(max),
          Comment  VARCHAR(max))          
          
INSERT INTO dest_server.dest_db_name.dbo.Products         
         (ProductID,
          ProductName,
          ProductDescription,
          Comment)
SELECT ProductID,
          ProductName,
          ProductDescription,
          Comment
FROM src_db_name.dbo.SourceProducts
```

I tried to set this on the target server [dest_server] on the database [dest_db_name] but I don't see the detailed information about the column.

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION 
  SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;
```

How to make this setting work with linked server queries.

Comment: Turning off warnings is never the solution. Fix your table to allow the longer content, or fix your data to shorten that content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server truncation error with specific column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77951143/sql-server-truncation-error-with-specific-column-name)

Comment: Compatibility level on the database needs to be >=150

Answer (score 0):

You could just run the following modified select statement, which highlights those offending records:

```sql
SELECT ProductID,
       ProductName,
       ProductDescription,
       Comment
FROM src_db_name.dbo.SourceProducts
WHERE
    LEN(ProductName) > 100 OR
    LEN(ProductDescription) > 500 OR
    LEN(Comment) > 500;
```

Comment: From [`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing spaces." A column with trailing spaces might not turn up in the output of this `select`, but still be too long for the `insert`. [`DATALENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) does not exclude trailing spaces, but the result must be corrected depending on the data type and character encoding.